# USB Mouse not working after installing Ubuntu 16.04 - Persistent Fix?

Tags: usb, mouse, 16.04

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 and I haven't any problem in live. But after the login, mouse doesn't move and click. 
the only solution I found was:

```
sudo rmmod usbhid
sudo modprobe usbhid
```

However, I have to run the commands every time I want to use the mouse,
some other solution?

I also tried adding usbhid in /etc/modules

OUTPUT dmesg:

```
[   88.343508] usb 2-1.2: Product:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE
[   88.346159] input:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:15D9:0A4C.0002/input/input15
[   88.402897] hid-generic 0003:15D9:0A4C.0002: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [ USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
[   88.917503] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
```

Comment: I also tried adding  usbhid in /etc/modules

Comment: Could you update your question with the following questions answered:
1. How old is the mouse? 2. What happens when you unplug and plug it in again, does it work or does it still require the rmmod and modprobe commands to work? 3. Can you provide the log ouput when connecting and disconnecting the mouse. Thanks

Comment: So, no general fix for this yet ?

Comment: These commands make no difference to my system.  The USB mouse continues to not work

Answer (score 4):

Not answer, just information.

Fedora user has same problem.
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1277837

In above url, developer suggest to try to stop fwupd
by setting EnableOptionROM=false in `/etc/fwupd.conf`.

Or prevent to start gnome-software by removing
`"/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-software-service.desktop"`.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.
When I disconnect  and reconnect the mouse after modprobe, the problem returns, with the same symptoms.

Some logs:

dmesg after disconnecting:

```
[252703.806012] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 9
```

After reconnecting:

```
[252795.656346] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[252795.753417] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=15d9, idProduct=0a4c
[252795.753424] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[252795.753428] usb 2-1.2: Product:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE
[252795.756554] input:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:15D9:0A4C.0012/input/input33
[252795.757510] hid-generic 0003:15D9:0A4C.0012: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [ USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
```

When moving the mouse/clicking after that:

```
[252897.603985] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
[252897.683981] usb 2-1.2: input irq status -75 received
```

that could be dozens of messages just the same.

After rmmod:

```
[253044.509863] usbcore: deregistering interface driver usbhid
```

After modprobe:

```
[253070.755169] input: HID 1267:0103 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:1267:0103.0013/input/input34
[253070.811506] hid-generic 0003:1267:0103.0013: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [HID 1267:0103] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1/input0
[253070.816279] input: HID 1267:0103 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.1/0003:1267:0103.0014/input/input35
[253070.871361] hid-generic 0003:1267:0103.0014: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [HID 1267:0103] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1/input1
[253070.874103] input:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:15D9:0A4C.0015/input/input36
[253070.927229] hid-generic 0003:15D9:0A4C.0015: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [ USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
[253070.927285] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[253070.927288] usbhid: USB HID core driver
```

...and now it works again.