# Left click doesn't work properly on Ubuntu 16 (fresh install)

Tags: 16.04, mouse

I've just installed Ubuntu 16 lts and my mouse (R.A.T.TE on a USB 3 port) only accepts about 20% of left clicks that I make, if I unplug it and plug in a old Logitech I found in my house it works (the R.A.T.TE works just fine in windows).Can anyone help me?

Comment: There is a slightly older, very similar question: https://askubuntu.com/q/763511 It doesn't have a solution thourg.

Answer (score 1):

Type the following into terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Then copy and paste the following into the editor that opens

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "Mouse Remap"
MatchProduct "Mad Catz Mad Catz R.A.T.TE"
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 0 0 8 9 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

Save and restart.

Comment: I've used that and now I don't have my mouse problem in recovery mode, however if I boot up normally I just get a black screen