# Mouse not working properly in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mouse, gui

I am facing issues with mouse(external) clicks, which start misbehaving every now and then (left click stops working, sometimes right, or it gets into the drag and select mode). Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Comment: Replace the mouse. Honestly, that is not the kind of questions expected here.

Comment: I have a similar problem on occasion, (usually in a VM) and have not yet tried this:  `sudo rmmod usbhid && sudo modprobe usbhid` may help.  Your question is very similar to [https://askubuntu.com/questions/763511/usb-mouse-not-working-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-persistent-fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763511/usb-mouse-not-working-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-persistent-fix) and [https://askubuntu.com/questions/813220/usb-mouse-not-working-after-upgrading-from-14-04-to-16-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813220/usb-mouse-not-working-after-upgrading-from-14-04-to-16-04)

Comment: Do(es) the same issue(s) occur with different mice or with the same mouse of a live system?

Comment: Yes, it occurs with different mice.